# How to put data from my database in SQL and put it on a textfield and label

Tags: sql, objective-c, sqlite

I am making a quiz that reads from the database in SQL and puts the question in the label view and the answers in the textfield. I have done a lot of tutorials that have similar solutions but they use a table view. Here is my attempt, I of course checked to see if I had a database and used:

```
   -(void) readProjectsFromDatabase {
sqlite3 *database;
projects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from t1";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            field1.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
                    field2.text = [array objectAtIndex:1];
            // Create a new project object with the data from the database
            Project *project = [[Project alloc] initWithName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl];
            // Add the project object to the project Array
            [projects addObject:project];
            [project release];
        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to initialize the array using the database file ? I am not sure if the database file can be used like this to initialize the array.

Why don't you use the projects array to set the fields ? It appears that it is successfully being populated in your `-(void) readProjectsFromDatabase`

Also try to put `NSLog` statements to see if the array is actually populated, if it is, then also check to see if `field1` and `field2` are properly connected in the interface builder to the corresponding outlets